# toggle only one li element on react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i would like to switch the colors between the active element on my project, but this way both of them are changing the style on click, how could i fix this? thanks!

```
function Language() {
  
  const [style, setStyle] = useState(false);
  
  const changeStyle = () => {   
    setStyle(!style);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul className="lang">
        {languages.map(({ code, name, country_code }) => (
          <li key={country_code}>
            <h4 onClick={() => {i18next.changeLanguage(code); changeStyle()}} className={style ? "cont" : "cont2"}>{name}</h4>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want only one element to have the class `cont` at once? Or do you want each of them to hold their own state?

Comment: @caTS only one at once, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a boolean as a state, you can try to use the index of the active element as the state:

```js
function Language() { 
  const [active, setActive] = useState(-1); // -1 represents no active element
 
  const changeStyle = (index) => {   
    setStyle(index);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul className="lang">
        {languages.map(({ code, name, country_code }, i) => ( // get index as i
          <li key={country_code}>
            <h4 onClick={() => {i18next.changeLanguage(code); changeStyle(i)}} className={active === i ? "cont" : "cont2"}>{name}</h4>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Then you'll be able to check if the index of this `li` is the same as the active index.

Comment: that works, i'm new on react as it probably shows hehe, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> You can set the code of the active li as the state value and check if the state value is equal to the code value of the li or any other unique value.

```
function Language() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState('');      
  const changeStyle = (code) => setActive(code)


  return (
    <>
      <ul className="lang">
        {languages.map(({ code, name, country_code }) => (
          <li key={country_code}>
            <h4 
                onClick={()=>{
                  i18next.changeLanguage(code);
                  changeStyle(code)
                }} 
                className={active===code && "active" }>
                  {name}
            </h4>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```