# JS/next.js: Why does a change to a map() element via document.querySelector() cause a rerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
const slides = [
    [string1, string2, stringi],
    [string1, string2, stringi],
    [string1, string2, stringi],
    [string1, string2, stringi],
];

const changeSlide = (num) => {
    const discipline = document.querySelector("#changeSlide-"+num)
    discipline.classList.toggle("hidden")
}

    return (
            <div className="flex flex-col w-1/2 h-60 px-12 py-4 items-center shadow-lg rounded-xl ring-1 ring-black/5">
                <h1 className="pb-2">
                    Technical Skills
                </h1>
                <ul className="flex space-x-2 border-b-2 mb-2">
                    <li>
                        <a href="" className="p-2 inline-block rounded-t-lg hover:bg-gray-200"
                            onClick={() => changeSlide(0)}>Software</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" className="p-2 inline-block rounded-t-lg hover:bg-gray-200"
                            onClick={() => changeSlide(1)}>Firmware</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" className="p-2 inline-block rounded-t-lg hover:bg-gray-200"
                            onClick={() => changeSlide(2)}>Mechanical</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" className="p-2 inline-block rounded-t-lg hover:bg-gray-200"
                            onClick={() => changeSlide(3)}>DevOps</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {slides.map(function(slide, idx) {
                    return <div className="hidden"
                                id={"changeSlide-"+idx}
                                key={idx}>
                                    {slide.map(function(line, jdx) {
                                        return <p key={jdx}>{line}</p>
                                        })
                                    }
                            </div>
                        })
                    }
        </div>
    )
}
```

[this is what this renders for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it3x6.png)

I want this react component to return the strings inside the slides array when the corresponding menu button is clicked. It does that. The problem is that the page seems to render again after the content is displayed. I say may because for all I know it could be rerunning the map function or something else.

I need to 1) find out what and why is happening after changeSlide(idx) is called onClick, and 2) what to do instead.

I am not sure if the above code will run since I deleted a lot of what I am actually using. I thought a simpler view would help. Let me know, and I will repost working code, but this should be best for illustrating the issue. Thanks.

Comment: More importantly, why are you using anti-React code? You don't need to use querySelector to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [toggle only one li element on react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74280707/toggle-only-one-li-element-on-react)

Comment: Also don't use an `a` element if it isn't a link, especially if using `Next.js` which provides a [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) component which is specifically designed to avoid the problem you're having and to navigate between routes without rendering issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the links have a set `href`, so clicking on it will navigate (to the current page again, as the href is an empty string). Either remove the href, prevent the default action on click, or use another element (perhaps a button) styled to look like a link.

Removing the href:

```
<a className="p-2 inline-block rounded-t-lg hover:bg-gray-200"
    onClick={() => changeSlide(0)}>Software</a>
```

Using `event.preventDefault()`:

```
<a href="" className="p-2 inline-block rounded-t-lg hover:bg-gray-200"
    onClick={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      changeSlide(0);
    }}>Software</a>
```

In addition, it is better to store the selected index in state rather than modifying the DOM manually.

Comment: Beautifully explained. Thank you. As for the state recommendation: use a single element and setState to the given index onClilck instead of map and query selecting?

Comment: @giveearholdtongue Yes, to display one section at a time, you can store the given index in state.